# Masturbating while thinking of someone

Tags: halal-haram

If I am very hot and horny (sorry for language) and I want to have sex with somebody. Instead of this to stop myself for doing zinaa I'm going to masturbate. According to fiqh it is better to do the less bad one. So masturbating shouldn't be that bad in this situation. I know looking at sexual videos is haraam, but to stimulate myself is it also haraam to think about someone (in a sexual way) you know or have seen in real life to stimulate yourself or is this also haraam?

Comment: You seem to be unmarried, so why don't you try fasting? It's very effective. Better still, find a good girl and get married lest this habit harms your character permanently.

Comment: Very likely an addiction. Please do see "[Hypersexuality, nymphomania and related medical conditions](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/30120/9123)". I hope it helps. Masturbation is considered haram according to many scholars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it haram to visualize having sex?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12901/is-it-haram-to-visualize-having-sex)

Answer (score 3):

Masturbation in form of self-stimulation is forbidden in Shi'ah fiqh. While describing the believers, the Qur'an says,

> "The believers are... those who protect their sexual organs except from their spouses... Therefore, whosoever seeks more beyond that [in sexual gratification], then they are the transgressors." (23:5-6)

The last sentence makes it very clear that any sexual gratification *outside marriage* is considered a transgression of the law of God.