# Is it haram to imagine someone you don't know naked?

Tags: halal-haram, sex

It started when I was 12 years old when I started thinking something lewd, like imagining someone (male/female) naked in front of or not in front of anyone.  I don't visualize myself and there and no one is having sex in my visualization.

Is it haram in Islam to imagine someone you don't know naked?

Comment: haram is a heavy word, but how can we judge imagination?? well i would recommend you to try to avoid thinking of somebody baked if necessary by fasting...

Comment: There is definitely a difference of opinion on this matter. But, this question is a Possible duplicate of [Is it haram to visualize having sex?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12901/is-it-haram-to-visualize-having-sex)

Comment: No not having sex dude,just naked xD and i dont visualize im there

Comment: Even though you're not there, deliberately visualizing is haram according to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is haram. As long as you don't act on it then it is ok. I think there is a hadith where the Prophet said "Allah has forgiven my followers the evil thoughts that occur to their minds, as long as such thoughts are not put into action or uttered." (Reported in the six authentic books of Hadith, and explained by Imam Ibn Kathir)"

Again you can double check with your Imam but this is my opinion.

Comment: *that occur to their minds*, is different from *deliberately causing them to occur*. Isn't it?