# Is it permissible to just listen to the sound of porn?

Tags: hadith, halal-haram, sex

Would it be halal if I just listened to it without masturbating or fantasizing about it?

Please mention verses from Quran and Hadith, not just your personal opinion.

Comment: I wonder why the question got downvoted. Anyways welcome to [islam.se].

Comment: This is just another way your subconscious brain figures out. Please do see "[Hypersexuality, nymphomania and related medical conditions](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/30120/9123)". I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Walaikumassalam wrwb.
That's how satan tempts us and deceives us in following seemingly small deeds which eventually leads to bigger sins.

> Then I will come to them from before them and from behind them and on their right and on their left, and You will not find most of them grateful [to You]. (Quran 7:17)

For example, first just a smile, then a handshake, then a chat, then the ultimate destruction: ZINA.

Speaking from an Islamic point of view its forbidden as Allah said in the Quran (Surah 6, Ayah 151-152)

> "Say, "Come, I will recite what your Lord has prohibited to you. [He
>   commands] that  you not associate anything with Him, and to parents,
>   good treatment, and do not kill your  children out of poverty; We will
>   provide for you and them. And **do not approach immoralities - what is
>   apparent of them and what is concealed**..."

And also in Surah Isra (17:32)

> "And do not **approach (come near to)** unlawful sexual intercourse.
>   Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way"

We have to be wary of the Satan's temptations and fooling. As in the case of listening to the sound of porn,without masturbating or fantasizing about then what's the logic behind listening to it? What's your intention or purpose?

However, it doesn't make sense in listening while restraining yourself from watching it and that's almost impossible.

Also the prophet said in a hadith (Sahih Bukhari):

> لاَ يُلْدَغُ الْمُؤْمِنُ مِنْ جُحْرٍ وَاحِدٍ مَرَّتَيْنِ 
>  A believer is not bitten from the same hole twice

So better not be foolish in attempting to be eventually addicted to porn

Answer (score 3):

Allah says in the quran in [Surah 6, Ayah 151-152](http://quran.com/6/151-152)

> Say, "Come, I will recite what your Lord has prohibited to you. [He commands] that you not associate anything with Him, and to parents, good treatment, and do not kill your children out of poverty; We will provide for you and them. **And do not approach immoralities - what is apparent of them and what is concealed**...

Also mention in [Surah 17, Ayah 32](http://quran.com/17/32)

> And do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way.

Sex outside marriage is considered immoral and what you mentioned is first step towards it.

How can you stop your mind from thinking about sex when you are listening this? Even if it somehow possible, why would you want to get close to something that is so dangerous (illegal sex)

I would recommend you not to do it

Comment: @goto....but if you were to consider a situation where given one does listen to audio porn without looking at any of that filth and have no possibility of committing Zina or coming close to Zina such as dating etc. Would it still be haram...given u are treating this act as an alternative to refrain from Zina or like thereof.

Comment: @EPICTubeHD Fasting is better alternative to refrain from Zina than listening to port

Comment: unfortunately it's not that practical given ppl's circumstances to fast everyday.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not halal but haram.  To listen to such filth is no difference then looking at it, [the Quran forbids](http://quran.com/17/32) from going near Zina:

> وَلَا تَقْرَبُوا الزِّنَا ۖ إِنَّهُ كَانَ فَاحِشَةً وَسَاءَ سَبِيلًا
>
> And do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an
>   immorality and is evil as a way.

From this Ayah we understand that every path that leads and can lead straight to this immorality has been blocked and made forbidden.  And by every path, I mean every single path, for there are paths especially for men (but also women) that lead to this immorality which is not necessarily limited to sight and touch, but also can be through sound.  As we understand it from the Authentic Ahadeeth narrated in Bukari and Muslim, every limb has it's Zina, and the Zina of the ears is listening to haram singing and talk, and or even sounds like what you mention in your question.

> والأذنان زناهما الاستماع
>
> the Zina of the ears is the listening (to voluptuous songs or talk)

[رياض الصالحين (Riyadussaliheen)](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18/112)

Comment: if you were to consider a situation where given one does listen to audio porn without looking at any of that filth and have no possibility of committing Zina or coming close to Zina such as dating etc. Would it still be haram...given u are treating this act as an alternative to refrain from Zina or like thereof.