# I am unmarried, how to keep myself clean?

Tags: sharia, sex

Every day I told myself how to protect myself, every day one or two opportunities comes to do bad things, I mean a sin like Zina or other things that brings me closer to adultery.

There is a very big pressure on me. To be honest, I don't have the ability for marriage right now, but I don't think marriage will totally solve this as it'll continue even after marriage.

Some time I tell myself, *comon, it's just one time* but I take a sin way to prevent the big mistake if you know what I mean.

So, I am asking you to be honest and show me a right way, I have ability for change. I can't handle this too much pressure anymore.

Jazakum allah.

Comment: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/189

Comment: @BleedingFingers: Thanks for you, I read the entire post in your comment and I am totally with you. But as you see, I really suffered from this problem, I didn't post this for collecting votes. As Allah said `وَشَاوِرْهُمْ فِي الأَمْرِ`. This was the only purpose, Thanks again.

Comment: @Azad You really should seek advice and counseling from a real world person a religious scholar and/or doctor, rather then taking the words of some random internet folk.

Comment: @BleedingFingers: I see great words from those people, I am sorry, I am not agree with you in that point.

Comment: @Azad It might be a great words. But it's not on-topic on this site. This will set incorrect trend on the site.

Comment: @BleedingFingers: I understand, Jazaku Allah for your efforts. At the end, you're make the rules and I will obey.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.** You cannot afford to ignore the fact that the married individual is more comfortable and is in a position to better perform his religious duties and obligations as he enjoys peace of mind and a tranquil heart. He is considered to have covered half of the way whereas an unmarried person struggles to safeguard his faith and himself against evil.

**2.** There is a tradition from Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) saying that the one who gets married, has safeguarded half of his/her religion so he/she must be wary of Allah in the other half.
as you can see getting married without being wary of Allah is not going to do the job.

**3.**

> If you are afraid lest you should fall into a sin as a result of not marrying, it is necessary that you should act according to the following pieces of moral advice so that you may remain immune against any error until you can afford marriage:
>
> 1. Fasting is very useful for controlling the physical desires and strengthening your will. If you are not capable of fasting, try to not
>      to overeat or at least your belly should not be full before going to
>      bed.
> 2. Do not eat the food that causes sexual excitement. Do not eat bananas, chocolates, figs, dates, onions, pepper, eggs, beef, oily
>      foods etc.
> 3. Always keep your bladder empty.
> 4. Read something before going to bed. Also do not sleep with your face down to the ground.[iv]
> 5. Although sexual problem is a reality, it appears to man bigger than it really is. Thus, he thinks that he cannot control it but the
>      reality is that man can overcome and control this problem with strong
>      will, firm determination and proper thinking.

source: http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1491

Comment: Please do see "[Hypersexuality, nymphomania and related medical conditions](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/30120/9123)". I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Indulge in prayer (Qur'an 29:45), keep fasting

> The Prophet (sal Allahu alaihi wa sallam) said: “Whoever among you can
>   afford it, let him get married, for it is more effective in lowering
>   the gaze and guarding chastity. And whoever cannot afford it, then let
>   him fast, for it will be restraint for him.” [Sunan an-Nasai]

and most of all make dua' and keep seeking refuge in Allah from shetaan (audubillah min ashaytaan arajeem). And Allah knows best. Brother one more thing it's only shaytaan who is telling ypu that you cant marry. Have trust and tawakal in Allah SWT.

Answer (score 0):

GIndulge in prayer (Qur'an 29:45), keep fasting

The Prophet (sal Allahu alaihi wa sallam) said: “Whoever among you can afford it, let him get married, for it is more effective in lowering the gaze and guarding chastity. And whoever cannot afford it, then let him fast, for it will be ......

Assalamu alaikum. Prayer 5 time daily if it possible prayer on night ask refuge to Allah daily...morning surathul nas and falak u read....