# Will I be forgiven if I can not control masturbation?

Tags: forgiveness, masturbation

I have recently converted to Islam, earlier I was an atheist and did very bad things, now I have changed and for the good, I am full of empathy and piety and help people. I have completely withdrawn myself from greed and lying, and dedicated myself to knowledge, wisdom and helping others.

I work a lot towards self improvement. However, one thing that I am not able to control is lust. I am unmarried and have had no girlfriends since I converted, however truthfully I still wander but come to my senses shortly. However I do masturbate, earlier I used to almost everyday but now I have cut it down to once a week and I deeply regret after doing it. I always ask Allah to show me the right way and help me be a better person and control myself and ask for forgiveness whenever I sin or have a thought of it.

After having tried and not being able to control it, I think I might never but I keep trying.

All I ask is will Allah forgive me? I do not crave for heaven if I am a bad soul I deserve hell but I cannot bear to have disappointed Allah and don't want to repent with my head down in front of him when I meet Him.

Comment: Allah will forgive you if you don't relapse and do your best to compensate for your past sins. You may also want to try my formula for controlling sexual urges for the unmarried: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12647/i-am-unmarried-how-to-keep-myself-clean#comment24338_12647

Comment: Please do see "[Hypersexuality, nymphomania and related medical conditions](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/30120/9123)". I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

First your are welcome to islam.

Yes ALLAH forgive you because He says:

> واستغفر الله إن الله كان غفورا رحيما
>
> And ask forgiveness of Allah; surely Allah has been Ever-Forgiving, Ever-Merciful.(Al-nisa)

And the Prophet (PBUH) says:

> وَيَتُوبُ اللَّهُ عَلَى مَنْ تَابَ
>
> And Allah forgives him who repents to Him.(Narrated by Muslim in the book of Zakat chapter 39)

But you must never repeat this sin and make a Tawba.

ALLAH Subhanaho Wa Ta'ala say:
[image]

**That's meaning that it not permissible to do any other thing that Jima'a with the wife.**

**1 -** Avoid the environment and media that arouse the sexual desires.

**2 -** Try not to delay marriage.

**3 -** Manage your spare time with useful activities!

**4 -** Choose good companionship(In Arabic الرفقة الصالحة).

**5 -** Performing fast (sawm) chastens the soul (nafs).

*The prophet Muhammed (Peace be upon him) in [Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/16/3) said:*

[image]

**Take a look at [this link](http://askaquestionto.us/article/morals/how-to-overcome-the-sexual-desires-and-masturbation) for more information.**

Comment: Okay @DavidWallace, I meant companionship, friends or brother. In Arabic الرفقة الصالحة

Answer (score 0):

> Abu Huraira reported from Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) that his Lord, the Exalted and Glorious, thus said. A servant committed a sin and he said: O Allah, forgive me my sins, and Allah (the Exalted and Glorious) said: My servant commited a sin and then he came to realise that he has a Lord Who forgives the sins and takes to account (the sinner) for the sin.
>
> He then again committed a sin and said: My Lord, forgive me my sin, and Allah, the Exalted and High, said: My servant committed a sin and then came to realise that he has a Lord Who would forgive his sin or would take (him) to account for the sin.
>
> He again committed a sin and said: My Lord, forgive me for my sin, and Allah (the Exalted and High) said: My servant has committed a sin and then came to realise that he has a Lord Who forgives the sins or takes (him) to account for sin. 0 servant, do what you like. I have granted you forgiveness.
>
> 'Abd al-A'la said: I do not know whether he said thrice or four times to do" what you desire". The hadlth has been narrated on the authority of 'Abd al-A'la b. Hammad with the same chain of transmitters.
>
> - Narrated by Muslim, Book 37 (Pertaining to Repentance and Exhortation to Repentance ), Chapter 5: REPENTANCE IS ACCEPTED SO LONG AS ONE REPENTS AFTER COMMITTING SINS

As long as you 'came to realise that you have a Lord Who forgives the sins or takes (him) to account for sin' and keep on fighting the urge to sin, Allah promises forgiveness.

One thing many muslims forget is that Dunia is not a place of rest. You will always be fighting your urges to sin as long as you live.

> [He] who created death and life to test you [as to] which of you is best in deed - and He is the Exalted in Might, the Forgiving
> [AlMulk 67:2]

Answer (score 0):

In your new region there is two model of marriage: permanent marriage when you have conditions as having a job and income that you can research about this and temporary marriage when you cant have a permanent marriage and this second model is for time you cant control your lust well and disturb.
Please certainly research about two model and certain study then according to your condition do one of them and dont disturb yourself.
Have a good life

Comment: Adding resources would be good

Answer (score -2):

Allah is merciful and compassionate. Be sure that Allah will forgive your sins if you repent correctly.

Islam recommends marriage for the improvement of people's life from sexual needs to way of life.