# How to avoid masturbation and sincerly repent doing it?

Tags: practical-islam, tawba, masturbation

Assalamualikum, 
i hope i can get answers because i am desperate, I'm a 19 years old girl, i used masturbate in the past by watching explicit images (astaghfirullah), but since i started praying regularly and wearing hijab i stopped and asked for repentance, now , after two years of abstinence sometimes i have sexual tension (it won't go away even if i fast or pray), so i end up masturbating (no insertion), just stimulation of a few minutes and then the orgasm, and i do that without watching or even thinking about explicit things, i only do it to release the tension, the think is, i try not to do it as much as possible but sometimes the temptation comes back and i keep asking Allah for forgiveness, i don't even know if it's really a big sin stimulating to release the sexual tension.

Do you have any advice on how can i definitely stop and will Allah swt forgive  me?
 I really feel guilty after doing it (and i do it like once in a month ), please i am desperate i really want to avoid it.

Comment: Relevant posts: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16405/masturbation-and-will-i-be-punished, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/masturbation-and-islam, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30278/what-is-the-punishment-for-masturbation-and-is-it-necessary-to-take-a-shower-aft and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12647/i-am-unmarried-how-to-keep-myself-clean?rq=1

Comment: i don't have the means to get married, i never have any contact with any men

Comment: Have you checked the "relevant" links and made a search on the site?

Comment: Try to engage with some activities with your sisters to avoid loneliness if is one of the causes. You may also do some research for the foods and herbs that reduce this kind of tension.

Comment: see https://sunnah.com/search/?q=fast+young .  Narrated `Abdullah: We were with the Prophet (ﷺ) while we were young and had no wealth whatever. So Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "O young people! Whoever among you can marry, should marry, because it helps him lower his gaze and guard his modesty (i.e. his private parts from committing illegal sexual intercourse etc.), and whoever is not able to marry, should fast, as fasting diminishes his sexual power."

Answer (score -2):

Reciting Quran-Al-Majeed day and night helped me a lot.
May Allah s.w.t guide you and help you.

Comment: Your answer needs elaboration. Please consider taking our [tour] checking our [help] and read [answer].