# Will Allah forgive me for repenting this sin (masturbation) so many times?

Tags: tawba, masturbation

I am a 16 year old Muslim boy. I discovered masturbation at the end of my 7th grade and have been addicted to it since then. I didn’t know it was Haraam. One day, I read an article about it and really got shocked and I stopped doing it for about a week and a half, but then I did it again unable to control myself. I couldn’t talk about it to anyone as it is so embarrassing. I always try to control it, but I fail. It just gets me depressed all the time when I think about the punishment I am going to get. I apologise to Allah when I pray but I end up doing it. I just couldn’t stop it.

After I masturbate, I observe that it affects my studies; I can't focus on my lessons.  I was a bright student up until when I was in my 7th grade, and now I'm in my 10th grade I am the weakest in my class. I am going to face my board examinations in March and I couldn’t concentrate on my studies. 
I wish I could get the best remedy in Islam.

Comment: See the links in the comments to [this question](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31159/how-to-avoid-masturbation-and-sincerly-repent-doing-it). Basically, the islamic position is "pray, keep yourself busy with righteous work, fast if you need to, and marry when you can".

Comment: see https://sunnah.com/search/?q=fast+young .  Narrated `Abdullah: We were with the Prophet (ﷺ) while we were young and had no wealth whatever. So Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "O young people! Whoever among you can marry, should marry, because it helps him lower his gaze and guard his modesty (i.e. his private parts from committing illegal sexual intercourse etc.), and whoever is not able to marry, should fast, as fasting diminishes his sexual power."

Comment: why this is "opinion based"?! i cannot agree with this.

Comment: My brother, depending on the Islamic opinion, masturbation is either Haram, makruh (disliked), and even mubah (permissible) according to Imam Al-Shawkani and some other scholars. What is absolutely unanimously haram is pornography so masturbating with pornography is unanimously haram as well.

Masturbation is a corporealizing act and you should try your best to avoid it but if you end up masturbating, ask for forgiveness and try not to do it again inshallah.

Answer (score 1):

- Ask Allah to help you. *ادْعُونِي أَسْتَجِبْ لَكُمْ*
- Increase your bond with Islam. Try to go more to the mosque. Read more of Quran and reflect. Don't just skim through it, get yourself a good teacher and try to understand it. Have you read the story of Yusuf? His story is somewhat related. But more generally Quran is a book that shows how each prophet was tested. They were humans as we are. We can related to their tests and apply it to our daily lives. This would make your heart come to peace. *أَلَا بِذِكْرِ اللَّهِ تَطْمَئِنُّ الْقُلُوبُ*
- fast. It would quench your thirst
- turn yourself towards your problem and analyze yourself and say when I do this...then I feel more like I want to masturbate. For instance when I go and play this (sexy) computer game or watch this TV show which has character X I usually tend to think more of masturbating.
- Sleep less. I don't mean sleep 3hrs a night. You can sleep 1-2 hrs less. Or sleep at different times. It actually boosts your effectiveness and diminishes your lust.
- Avoid bad friends. Bad friends are people who speak about Movie X, TV show Y, bad books, bad jokes, bad drinks, bad parties. Basically it's hard to be with them and remember Allah. Find yourself Good friends.
- If you aren't fasting still, eat less. Skip lunch. In general the Islamic way doesn't include lunch. It's usually only breakfast and dinner.
- Do sports or any other hobby. They would keep your mind busy and attached while make you less lustful.
- Try to have a goal, like be the top student. Try learning a skill like learning drawing, or graphic design or programming or selling, etc. Get yourself in touch of a mentor and have them guide you.
- Don't think of masturbation as a lesser sin of Zina. The moment you do such you have belittled Allah by belittling a sin.
- In addition, always always do *توبه* and seek Allah's forgiveness. I don't mean sin and then say Allah will forgive. I mean don't sin, but if you did, then Always go straight to Allah and ask his forgiveness. He's forgiving:

  *قُلْ يَا عِبَادِيَ الَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلَىٰ أَنفُسِهِمْ لَا تَقْنَطُوا مِن رَّحْمَةِ اللَّهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ جَمِيعًا ۚ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ*

*Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."*

Comment: i would say it is a perfect answer , i will add one more extra thing always fill your time with homeworks or activities , try to keep your self busy and don't create much leisure .

Comment: @mhdjazmati Thanks for the suggestion. I made a small edit