# Can I masturbate in a clean way?

Tags: taharah, ghusl, masturbation

I have a huge problem of masturbation.  My sexual desires are too strong, and  I have been masturbating since around 2009.  Since I often masturbate at night, I have to take Ghusul before prayer.  I sleep and cannot wakeup for fajir because I'm not clean and I am too lazy to take a bath.

Is there any way I can masturbate in a clean way?

Like in the bathroom and I clean my penis and don't get contact with sperm, for example.  I clean my penis well, and make sure that sperms doesn't come in contact with my body or clothes.

Comment: I identified the question in the post, and deleted material irrelevant to the question.

Comment: 1. are you asking is there any way to legalize what you are doing? or 2. just asking how can you masturbate which you know is a sin in a clean way? first question: No! ____ second question: Well why do you care to be clean or not? Don't you think the more important thing is to not do it all?! See [how can I stop masturbating](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36703/how-can-i-stop-masturbating/37278#37278)

Answer (score 5):

No, you have to make Ghusl. The reason is not whether or not the sperm touches the body, but with the fact that an ejaculation happened. If an ejaculation happens, then Ghusl is obligatory. ([source](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=283417))

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, masturbation is haram and you must immediately stop. Allah says in the Qu'ran, 
"And those who guard their chastity (i.e. private parts, from illegal sexual acts). Except from their wives or (the captives and slaves) that their right hands possess, - for them, they are free from blame. But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors." 23.5-7 Here the verses are clear in forbidding all illegal sexual acts (including masturbation) except for the wives or that their right hand possess. And whoever seeks beyond that is the transgressor.

"And let those who find not the financial means for marriage keep themselves chaste, until Allah enriches them of His bounty." 24.33. This verse also clearly orders whoever does not have the financial means to marry to keep himself chaste and be patient in facing temptations (including masturbation) until Allah enriches them of His 
bounty.

Based on these verses, masturbation is haram for all Muslims but some scholars say that you can only do it for a fertility test. You are delaying your salah and missing them is a very major sin so you must repent as much as you can.
If your sexual desires are high, then you should marry, if you cannot then you should fast as it would keep you away from evil desires.
For more information go to :
https://islamqa.info/en/329

Answer (score 1):

Ejaculation and even orgasm without ejaculation makes your impure whole body inside.

If you took bath and then touch or contact with ejaculated sperm that doesn't makes you impure.

The best solution for you is to get married as soon as possible and if it's not possible at this time try to fast every other day to lower your sexual desires.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean way to manstrubation. Its punishable if u do it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

masturbate but don't tell anyone or publicize. its your deed answerable to Allah SWT.
same as you fast and hold your thirst and hunger but don't eat or drink even when alone.