# is it permissible for a teenager to watch porn?

Tags: sharia

I f a teenager is desperate knowing sex is haraam before marriage and he or she cannot suppress their desires is it permissible to watch porn instead?

Comment: It is haram as other people within those videos are naked and committing Zina which is against Islam's teachings, plus as a muslim your not allowed to view other people naked! human has desires and these desires shall be controlled they are a test for us in this life, watching such videos will only make your desire stronger and by time the watcher will get bored of the video and do something else (Zina), as a muslim if you think of wrong and not do it as its a sin you will be rewarded 10 deeds

Comment: I heard a hadith which states that you can't even or should not look to the animals while they are doing this.

Comment: Please do see "[Hypersexuality, nymphomania and related medical conditions](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/30120/9123)". I hope it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is pornography allowed in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21524/is-pornography-allowed-in-islam)

Answer (score 2):

In the Quran (Surah 6, Ayah 151-152)

> Say, Come, I will recite what your Lord has prohibited to you. [He commands] that you not associate anything with Him, and to parents, good treatment, and do not kill your children out of poverty; We will provide for you and them. **And do not approach immoralities - what is apparent of them and what is concealed**...

and also While describing the believers, the Qur'an says,

> The believers are... those who protect their sexual organs except from their spouses... Therefore, whosoever seeks more beyond that [in sexual gratification], then they are the transgressors. (23:5-6)

The last sentence makes it very clear that any sexual gratification outside marriage is considered a transgression of the law of God.

Answer (score 0):

It is stated that it is not forbidden to look at the image of women's body in the water or in the mirror according to some Shafi‘i jurists, even with lust.

Ibn Abidin, a Hanafi jurist, wrote: "*I couldn't find anything about the disadvantage of looking at pictured private parts, let them be investigated.*" It is stated that some of Ottoman sultans who are considered as caliph have obscene miniatures in their miniature collections.

https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=wJx0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT315&dq=%22%D9%88%D8%AE%D8%B1%D8%AC+%D8%A8%D9%87+%D8%B1%D8%A4%D9%8A%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9+%D9%81%D9%8A+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1+%D8%A3%D9%88+%D9%81%D9%8A+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A2%D8%A9+%D9%81%D9%84%D8%A7+%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85+%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88+%D9%85%D8%B9+%D8%B4%D9%87%D9%88%D8%A9%22&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7oeOVpaDpAhUQ2aYKHREYCAAQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D9%88%D8%AE%D8%B1%D8%AC%20%D8%A8%D9%87%20%D8%B1%D8%A4%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1%20%D8%A3%D9%88%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A2%D8%A9%20%D9%81%D9%84%D8%A7%20%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85%20%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88%20%D9%85%D8%B9%20%D8%B4%D9%87%D9%88%D8%A9%22&f=false

https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=d1R7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT99&dq=%22%D9%88%D8%AE%D8%B1%D8%AC+%D8%A8%D9%87+%D8%B1%D8%A4%D9%8A%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9+%D9%81%D9%8A+%D9%86%D8%AD%D9%88+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A2%D8%A9+%D9%88%D9%85%D9%86%D9%87+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1+%D9%81%D9%84%D8%A7+%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85+%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88+%D9%85%D8%B9+%D8%B4%D9%87%D9%88%D8%A9%22&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr8cTmpKDpAhU6wcQBHXsOBawQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D9%88%D8%AE%D8%B1%D8%AC%20%D8%A8%D9%87%20%D8%B1%D8%A4%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D9%86%D8%AD%D9%88%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A2%D8%A9%20%D9%88%D9%85%D9%86%D9%87%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1%20%D9%81%D9%84%D8%A7%20%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85%20%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88%20%D9%85%D8%B9%20%D8%B4%D9%87%D9%88%D8%A9%22&f=false