# Masturbation is haram but what is the scientific reason?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, science, masturbation

[topic is masturbation but the question is different. So please read before marking it duplicate/negative. I've already read whole masturbation discussion and posting because I didn't find answer to my question]

I am a Muslim and a sciences student. My religion asks me to think and ponder over things. Similar to all other people of my age, masturbation is also my concern as sex is my need and I am not going to get married soon.

Whenever I search about Masturbation online, dozens of links from health forums, doctors' blogs and research authorities come up. Almost all of them declare masturbation as a good, normal and healthy habit with no harm to your health. Some of them claim that this is a result of scientific research. (I'll provide list of all links if someone need it).

On the other hand, Islam declares it Haram and Muslim scholars also declare it fatal for your physical and sexual health. There are many 'waeeed' in Islam for doing this act. (Source: Not only this forum but many books from Muslim Scholars)

Now I am extremely confused about these two different opinions. Being a Muslim, I believe that Islam only forbids us from fatal things. But on the other hand, it is also difficult to ignore all these things coming up every day. Please show me the right path.

Jazak Allah

Comment: You can find scientific benefits and harm of masturbation.  Not exactly sure how you concluded it was haraam, but scuence supports both good and bad.

Comment: Science is just an understanding of Human knowledge based on Our own observations, Science can never tell us that what is Ultiamely good or bad for us. but Allah's knowldge is perfect and beyond complete. Thats why whatever Allah tells us, it is best, and science is nothing infront of it

Comment: @Farhan, I am curious what you call "Ultimately good". Also, all you can claim is what Islam says, you should not use lightly words such as "Allah tells". Now to Sohail, can you please supply your sources about masturbation and about Islam **only** forbidding **fatal** things.

Comment: this space will be very small for explainnig it

Comment: How will you arouse yourself without seeking means to illegal things? See also "[The logic on prohibiting the pornography](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30419/9123)"

Comment: Sex is good for health definitely, but masturbation without a wife infront you is (very very) bad  =for your religion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a site about science.

Answer (score -1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

**"And those who do not have the means to get married must keep chaste till Allah provides them the resources by His munificence;.."(Quran 24:33)**

One must know that scientific facts should not be considered as absolute or final proof as it is constantly changing and improving.So if today you get to see some clear good healthy benefits more then later on it could get changed, you could find harmful effects as well,Although Islam and Science has coherence but we should not assume Islam as proving facts of "Science" solely but Islam as showing us clear "Signs" and evidences.

There is a consensus among scholars in every group of school that Masturbation is a disliked act and one has to avoid it, Regarding harms of masturbation  scientifically so read [this](http://www.homeoint.org/site/ahmad/masturbation.htm).One has to stop this practice on its own as nobody else could help in it ,it has to get stopped completely as Islam is about submitting oneself to the will of Allah Swt and In Sha Allah when a person leaves something for Allah Swt then he is blessed by something more good in this world and hereafter and fasting would help in it as mentioned in Hadith,

> It was narrated that 'Abdullah said: "We went out with the Messenger
>   of Allah and we were young men who could not afford anything. He said:
>   'O young men, you should get married, for it is more effective in
>   lowering the gaze and protecting one's chastity. Whoever cannot afford
>   it should fast, for it will be a restraint Wija, for him."'(Sunan An
>   Nasai)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: @SohailAslam The linked website displays an atrocious amount of antiscientific mumbo jumbo. If you'd like to know more about masturbation for a health point of view, I'd ask [health.se] instead.