# I heard its okay to have bisexual thoughts but never ever persue it. What is considered "acting on it"?

Tags: homosexuality

No one knows I'm attracted to the same gender  I'm a teen, so I'm obviously very attached to my phone. I have read lesbian stories on Wattpad (ebook app) and watch some lesbian youtubers on youtube. But I will never persue a relationship because my faith in Allah makes me confident I will never marry a girl. But is what I have done (the reading) considered as "acting on it"?

Comment: Stay from those things which trigger those thoughts in your brain. Please do see "[Hypersexuality, nymphomania and related medical conditions](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/30120/9123)". I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Brain is the center of our body, if it is faulty then our body cannot be okay. Thinking can affect our intentions and it can lead us to do as intended.

If you say you have faith in Allah, which will defend you from doing such an act than why don't you try to avoid watching/reading such act. Don't you think it is as bad as doing it?

Surely, if a Muslim intend a sin, it won't be written until he commits. But this does not mean you are free to think of sins, it can weaken your faith.

> **"‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ كَتَبَ عَلَى ابْنِ آدَمَ حَظَّهُ مِنَ الزِّنَا، أَدْرَكَ ذَلِكَ لاَ مَحَالَةَ، فَزِنَا الْعَيْنِ النَّظَرُ، وَزِنَا اللِّسَانِ الْمَنْطِقُ، وَالنَّفْسُ تَمَنَّى وَتَشْتَهِي، وَالْفَرْجُ يُصَدِّقُ ذَلِكَ، وَيُكَذِّبُهُ ‏"**
>
> I did not see anything so resembling minor sins as what Abu Huraira said from the Prophet, who said, "Allah has written for the son of Adam his inevitable share of adultery whether he is aware of it or not: The adultery of the eye is the looking (at something which is sinful to look at), and the adultery of the tongue is to utter (what it is unlawful to utter), and the innerself wishes and longs for (adultery) and the private parts turn that into reality or refrain from submitting to the temptation.

There are many things mentioned in this Hadith, like watching with eyes. It is also mentioned that it is not a minor sin.

Answer (score -1):

It's not okay to have such thoughts. Is it okay to have thoughts of robbing but then not robbing because you believe in God? 
You shouldn't think of such stuff, neither should you see / read stuff related to these. 
If you already have had such thoughts, it's high time you repent to Allah and Inshallah He will forgive you, and make Tawbah, and ask for His help and pray so that you don't get such thoughts. 
Hope this helps sister. 
You're mentioning about a Hadith which says that "if a person thinks of something evil and doesn't do it, then it's counted as if he didn't do it". Fine, but this doesn't mean you will always think of such stuff and later not do it. This is about something evil that came in to your mind all of a sudden and you didn't do it, not regular stuff. 
God bless.