# Is there a non-haram way for a teenage Muslim to pleasure himself?

Tags: halal-haram, sexuality

I don't masturbate or watch porn or any of that nasty stuff, but sometimes I get a really big temptation to do it. Granted i do resist, but I don't think I can for much longer. Is there any non-haram way to exaust that temptation

Comment: best halal way is to fast,if you cannot marry

Comment: Please do see "[Hypersexuality, nymphomania and related medical conditions](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/30120/9123)". I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Narrated `Abdullah:

> We were with the Prophet (ﷺ) while we were young and had no wealth
>   whatever. So Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "O young people! Whoever
>   among you can marry, should marry, because it helps him lower his gaze
>   and guard his modesty (i.e. his private parts from committing illegal
>   sexual intercourse etc.), and whoever is not able to marry, should
>   fast, as fasting diminishes his sexual power."

Sahih al-Bukhari 5066
 Book 67, Hadith 4

Comment: I myself find  that stacking more and more information about islam is really helpful, for example, realizing a sin that is committed in solitude has a big consequences in the hereafter

Answer (score 0):

This is based on my knowledge of Islamic traditional medicine and science of human *nafs*:

If you can't marry soon, do some of these:

- Drink more water, avoid spicy food, reduce your meat intake, and fast.
- Control your imagination, strengthen your mental/spiritual strength (study, doing math, prayer, meditation and focus are some of the ways), and do physical exercise.