# Will someone become unholy or impure if he/she masturbates?

Tags: sharia

If someone masturbates will he become unholy, impure? If yes, how can he regain his purity?

Comment: Of course all of the sins alter the man's soul let alone such an obscene sin. You'd better change the title and context so that it represents the second question, "...How can he regain... ."

Comment: Think about it this way to stop you from doing it in the future, Your getting nothing out of it and its making you have a stronger desire(Mentally) for women which may lead to physical zina, and its making you gain more sins through your eyes, plus it alters your way of thinking and your mental condition because it is not actual intercourse nor equivalent, inshallah you will get maried and this stage will be over, we learn to control desires not fulfill them by what gains us sins

Answer (score 4):

There is a tradition reported from Imam Ja’far as-Sadiq (a.s.):

> **أَبُو عَلِيٍّ الْأَشْعَرِيُّ عَنْ عِيسَى بْنِ أَيُّوبَ عَنْ عَلِيِّ
>   بْنِ مَهْزِيَارَ عَنِ الْقَاسِمِ بْنِ عُرْوَةَ عَنِ ابْنِ بُكَيْرٍ
>   عَنْ زُرَارَةَ عَنْ أَبِي جَعْفَرٍ ع قَالَ قَالَ: مَا مِنْ عَبْدٍ
>   إِلَّا وَ فِي قَلْبِهِ نُكْتَةٌ بَيْضَاءُ فَإِذَا أَذْنَبَ ذَنْباً
>   خَرَجَ فِي النُّكْتَةِ نُكْتَةٌ سَوْدَاءُ فَإِنْ تَابَ ذَهَبَ ذَلِكَ
>   السَّوَادُ وَ إِنْ تَمَادَى فِي الذُّنُوب زَادَ ذَلِكَ السَّوَادُ
>   حَتَّى يُغَطِّيَ الْبَيَاضَ فَإِذَا غَطَّى الْبَيَاضَ لَمْ يَرْجِعْ
>   صَاحِبُهُ إِلَى خَيْرٍ أَبَداً وَ هُوَ قَوْلُ اللَّهِ عَزَّ وَ جَلَّ-
>   كَلَّا بَلْ رانَ عَلى‏ قُلُوبِهِمْ ما كانُوا يَكْسِبُونَ**

“There is no servant who does not have a white spot in his heart. When he commits a sin a black spot emerges from this spot. If he repents, the blackness goes away but if he insists on committing sins and continues doing so the blackness keeps on increasing till it covers up the whiteness of the heart completely. When the white spot is totally covered by the blackness, the owner of this heart will never go back to goodness. and this is the meaning of Allah's word:

> **“No indeed! Rather their hearts have been sullied by what they have been earning." (83:14)**

In verse 53 of Surah Zomar we read:

> **قُلْ يا عِبادِيَ الَّذينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلى‏ أَنْفُسِهِمْ لا تَقْنَطُوا مِنْ رَحْمَةِ اللَّهِ إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ
>   جَميعاً إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحيمُ**
>
> **Say] that Allah declares, [" O My servants who have committed excesses against their own souls, do not despair of the mercy of
>   Allah. Indeed Allah will forgive all sins. Indeed He is the
>   All-forgiving, the All-merciful.**

The first step of repentance is to be sincerely sorry and regretful and make a conscious and strong decision not to commit sins again and in order for one to be able to take this step he has to deepen an understanding of the nature of the sins.

The second step is to make up for what he has done before. If he has violated others' rights he should compensate for them. If he has ignored Allah's rights, for instance, he has missed some obligatory prayers, he should decide to make up for them as soon as possible.

For further information please visit the following link:
**http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1627**

Answer (score 3):

Yes he does by indulging in such acts ipso facto as it constitutes zina of eyes and thoughts. However, its salvageable by seeking forgiveness from Allah.

> "And Allah would turn to you in mercy; but those who follow vain desires would have you go tremendously astray"
>
> "And who is further astray than he who follows his desire without guidance from Allah."
>
> "And those who guard their chastity (i.e. private parts, from illegal sexual acts). Except from their wives or (the captives and slaves) that their right hands possess, - for them, they are free from blame. But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors."
>
> "And let those who find not the financial means for marriage keep themselves chaste, until Allah enriches them of His bounty."

From Abu Muhammad Hadith

> None of you (truly) believes until his desire or inclination is in accordance with what I have brought or subservient to what I came with

From all those above Quaranic verses and one hadith its clear that to remain an ardent follower we have to abstain from all considered haram including masturbation.

Now to get back to being pristine, you will have to undo what harm has been done and guard yourself from repeating it. If you surrender yourself to the shade of Allah, you will not astray. To seek forgiveness recite "**astagfirullah(I seek forgiveness from Allah)**" at least 133 times with full heart after the act so done(Better if you make it a proclivity). Insha'Allah you will be forgotten.

To beat the temptation indulge in dhikr **SubhanAllahi, al adheem, wa bihamdihi, SubhanAllahil azim** (Glorified is Allah, The Supreme, Praised is he, Allah is free from imperfections) at least 100 times morning and evening besides salat. This will purify your thoughts, heart and shield your nafs from temptations invigorated by Satan.

Comment: please mention the surah and ayah numbers of verses quoted.